# How to go about setting value in dropdown?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, converters

I am currently studying level 3 ICT, I have done some VBS before, I created some currency exchange software last year, but this year is a bit more advanced, and I have this question.

I need to create a program that will convert lux to foot-candles and from foot-candles to lux.

This require me to use a drop down for the user to pick what they want to convert. So I made this form:

[image]

So there is going to be a drop down where you pick which way you want to convert. So Foot-candles to lux or lux to foot-candles. And I am not sure how to make it so it changes the convert rate.
footcandle = lux / 10.764
lux = footcandle / 0.0929

So this is what the software needs to do:
The  program  should  allow  the  user  to  select  whether  they  want  to  convert from  lux  or  from  foot-candles.   It  must  let  the  user  key  in  the  number  that they  want  converted.   It  must  show  the  result  of  calculating  what  this  is equivalent  to  in  the  other  unit.   It  must  let  the  user  continue to  another conversion or quit.

The problem is I don't know how to make it so the drop down has a value in it, I spend few hours looking and trying to work out how to put a value behind a text. I have values in the drop down, but what next. I'm not sure how to give them a numeric value.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is, I just created A Visual Basic Windows Forms Application, so yes

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. There are plenty of VB.Net tutorials out there; Google or whatever your preferred search engine is should be able to find one for you. How to use a ComboBox control should be covered in that tutorial.

Comment: You need to use MSDN to find Drop Down control you are using, go to example and you will see how to do it

Comment: One of the properties for a combo box is a collection of its members. The collection is of type object and will automatically look for properties .text to display in the combobox and .value for returning a value as object. Text values can easily be assigned to this collection via the properties window.

Comment: The collection property goes by the name Items under the data category.